# ASP.NET MVC development with Notepad?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, ide

So do I NEED Visual Studio of some flavor to do ASP.NET MVC development or could I technically do it all with a simple text editor? If YES, please tell me the catches, like if there is anything special I would have to do besides making the folder structure right and making sure my code is solid, etc.

Comment: The catches would fill a large blog entry.

Comment: You don't NEED a cup to drink water.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need a compiler, but you could use Notepad as your editor if you really wanted to. However, I would recommend using Visual Studio - it has all the help and support (IntelliSense etc.) you need.

You can download the [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/download/) edition for web development for free. The [MVC extensions](http://www.asp.net/mvc/download/) work with this.

Comment: I agree and I see no reason to use Notepad when VS is free.

Comment: SharpDevelop is free if you are wanting an alternative to VS - http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/

Answer (score 22):

Define 'NEED', technically all you need is [this](http://www.geeks3d.com/20080802/the-ultimate-keyboard-for-real-coder/): [image]
<sub>(source: [geeks3d.com](http://www.geeks3d.com/public/jegx/200808/keyboard-for-real-coder-big.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Or a tiny magnet and a steady hand :)

Comment: Or you can ditch your keyboard and just use a 3 button mouse. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

oh no - please say you're joking. as said, the free version gives you sooo much more.

that said, relying on basics can be very good!!